# How to make numxepr operate with complex64?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numexpr

I am trying to execute this code:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

def julia(h, w, maxit=20, a=0.0):
    x = np.linspace(-1.8, 1.8, w, dtype=np.float32)
    y = np.linspace(-1.8, 1.8, h, dtype=np.float32)
    xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    c = xv+yv*1j
    z = c
    divtime = maxit + np.zeros(z.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    q = np.complex64(0.7885*np.exp(1j*a))

    for i in range(maxit):
        ne.evaluate('z*z + q', out=z) # line with error
        diverge = z*np.conj(z) > 4
        div_now = diverge & (divtime == maxit)
        divtime[div_now] = i
        z[diverge] = 2
    return divtime

julia(100, 100)
```

Variables `z` and `q` are both `complex64` type, but numexpr returns `complex128`. Is there a way to make it operate with `complex64` values to increase performance?

Comment: How about `z = ne.evaluate('z*z + q')`?

Comment: @Divakar it works, but when i run it with 'out=z' it gives error 

'TypeError: Iterator requested dtype could not be cast from dtype('complex128') to dtype('complex64'), the operand 0 dtype, according to the rule 'safe''

I suppose that it internally converts complex64 to complex128 and I don't want that

Comment: Because `z` has a dtype of complex64, while the result of `'z*z + q'` would be `complex128`, so you can't write back into `z`?